Dhcp range with fixed Ips
Here I have a DHCP server with some IPs with fixed IPs that are in the range 192.168.1.91-254.
And for the leases only the range 192.168.1.11-90.
But I want to make the lease range bigger can I use another range like 192.169.1.0-254?
I didn't find a useful answer about how I do this or if I can do this.
My DHCP config is this way:
option domain-name "myServer.local";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option routers 192.168.1.3;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option domain-name "MyServer";
        option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1;
        option time-offset -18000;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.1.3;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
        range 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.90;
        default-lease-time 21600;
        max-lease-time 43200;
        # Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.
        [List with my fixed IPs]
}

I can make another subnet with the range 192.169.1.0 192.169.1.254 like this:
subnet 192.169.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.169.1.0 192.169.1.254;
        default-lease-time 21600;
        max-lease-time 43200;
}


It will work?
Or I just can modify the range in the main config to range 192.169.1.0 192.169.1.254
Thanks guys.

It's better to simply expand the range in the main config. If you have only one range, you don't have to worry about the problem of networks becoming disjoint (as you've set DNS to be entirely outside your network, your machines can't find each other by name using DNS), and you don't have to worry about range options becoming disparate due to forgetfulness or typos. DHCP generally won't issue an address that's already in use, it checks to see if an address is already claimed before it issues it, but to be safe you might consider changing your current static addresses to reservations, or adding reservations for them even if they're statically defined.
If your existing range is already far too heavily populated to gain you much by allowing the DHCP server to allocate addresses in the ranges where it is not, you can expand the overall range, as
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 {
        option routers 192.168.1.3;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.254.0;
        option domain-name "MyServer";
        option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1;
        option time-offset -18000;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.1.3;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
        range 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.254;
        default-lease-time 21600;
        max-lease-time 43200;
        range 192.168.1.11 192.168.1.90;
        default-lease-time 21600;
        max-lease-time 43200;
        # Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.
        [List with my fixed IPs]
}

This does have two disadvantages - first, you'll have to go into all your static assignments, to change the netmask to match the new network. And second, because it's now allocating from a 512-address range, it will be a bit nonstandard.

But how can I expand this range? The actual range is .11/.90 and in the reserved almost all others are in use.
If I use range .11/.254 the IPs that are not reserved become useful to the lease and the others (that are already reserved) stay reserved?

See my edited answer above. You really don't want to have a disjoint network by accident.

I think I get it. But I think this will give me a lot of work... sorry for keeping asking, but if I change my actual range to 1.10/1.254 and change some of my reserved IPs to something like 192.168.2.xxx it will work? Because I'll have more free IPs on range 1.10, and when the leases search for IP it can use the range .1.xxx. I think that changing all my reserved IPs is not the best solution.

The big problem is that 192.168.1.x/24 and 192.168.2.x/24 are disjoint and so communication between them have to go through a router unless you establish a lot of individual routes between them. That's why I was suggesting that you go to 192.168.0.x/23 - a non-disjoint network that includes 1.x and 2.x would also include 0.x and 3.x.

Hmm ok, now I get it. I will try this. First I'll change the range to .1.10/.1.254 because looking for my reserved IPs I have something about 110 reserved IPs. So I have a lot of possible free IPs to use. And one of my reserves is .1.30 which is in the range leases, so I think that all others will not be a problem.
